# Why does my watcher gets called twice on the same change?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an AngularJS 1.4* application running locally (yet). This app is served by an Laravel 5.1 backend RESTFul API.

I have to make this app that represents a package trip. A package is composed by days, ranging from 0 to N days. Each day have a list of services, ranging from 0 to N services. And a hotel.

My web server, from which my laravel application consumes from, delivers me a pre-setted package, containing a list of days: each one with a list of services and a hotel data (unused so far). On the response I have a list of properties for the package (that don't matter for now) and an array of days, called `days_info`. That response is being put in the `$scope.package`, on my `PackageController`. The **PackageController** also declares an directive called `packageBlock`, that consists in a list of days, and some other data for the package.

```
<div ng-repeat="day in package.days_info" class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
        <package-days-block></package-days-block>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside `<package-days-block>` directive, I have another to iterate through the list of services inside every day.

```
<div class='container-fluid' ng-repeat='service in day.services' ng-controller="ServiceController">
    <service-block></service-block>
</div>
```

That's where the problem begins: to my undestandment, I now have a `$scope.service` inside my `ServiceController`. So, I started to change it on my need inside the `ServiceController` through a `$scope.service`.

The **$scope.service** has an attribute called `service_id`. I put a listener/watcher on it, so at any time the **$scope.service.service_id** is changed, I ask for another `service_table` (holds the informations about the services, it's based on the service_id previously choosen or changed by the user), and put it in the `$scope.service.table`.

```
// ServiceController
$scope.reloadServicesTable = function(service_id, service_day, date, paxes){
    MandatoryService.getServiceTable(service_id, service_day, date, paxes)
    .then(
        function(service_data) {
            $scope.service.table = service_data;
        }, 
        ...
    );
```

The `reloadServicesTable` is called on the watcher for the **service_id** changes.

```
// ServiceController
$scope.$watch(
    'service.service_id', // Places the watcher to watch the changes on the service's ID.
    function(new_service, old_service) {
        if( new_service === old_service )
            return; 

        $scope.reloadServicesTable($scope.service.service_id, $scope.service.service_day, $scope.day.date, $scope.package.paxes);

    }
);
```

The problem starts here: the request for the service's table is called twice when the service_id only changes once.

**WHY, GOD, WHY?!**

There's another part of my code where I, from the *PackageController*, run through the entire `days_info` array and reads the value of an attribute `price` inside the service.table: `service.table.price`. In there, I realise that there's two **scope**'s: the one I handling and the other that I have no **FREAKING IDEA** where it came from!

If I put an `console.log($scope);` inside the method that runs through the *days_info*, I get two scopes for every request. This method is on the *PackageController*.

Any ideas why this is happening?

P.S.: It's my very first AngularJS application, so, take easy if I messed up on something basic...

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by an fellow on the comments, my question wasn't very reproducible. Sadly, I can't put here only the part I'm having doubts cause I don't have the slightest idea where the problem lies! (I know that this isn't much of help)

I took some screen shots from the Chrome Console:

First, the requestions fired on the change of the service_id

[image: Request log for the service change (ordered by path name)]

As you can see, every request is called twice everytime. This is not an one-time-thing. The `/api/service/{id}...` is the call for the service's table information. The `/api/service/by_route/origin/...` returns an list of services from one city to another (or the same). One does not interfere on the other.

The other image is the output from a **console.log** from the PackageController $scope, on the time that the service_id is being changed.

[image: Scopes for the PackageController]

As you can see, there's two different scopes. And the `b` scope is son of the `r` scope. The `r` scope is also calling the watcher on the `service_id`?

The call for the sums price is been called twice from differente places, as you can see in the image below:

[image: Call Stack for the sumPrices method on PackageController]

Comment: Your question is too long and contains a lot of irrelevant information, but lacks a reproducible test case. So it's hard to understand what the problem really is. But the documentation says: *[...] In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.

Comment: Usually, using a watch is a bad idea. If you told us, in a simple way, what you want to achieve, we could help you find a better way.

Comment: I am comparing the two values (newValue and oldValue) in the fn called after the compare function. This doesn't seems to be the problem (anymore). Since the function is been systematically called twice! I will put two prints from my request network log and a scope for a request on the change of the service.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but make sure **ServiceController** isn't instantiated twice. Also, you have around 8800 watchers which is terrible performance wise.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to iterate through the neasted scope and retrieve a information in it's deeper info/leaf. I put a watcher on the leaf, so when it changes, it tell his father/root that a change has heppened, and it should re-do the calculations. But, it seems that I have two scopes, being one inside the other($scope inside $rootScope, maybe). So, when the watcher event is fired, its been called once by the $scope and other by the $rootScope and I would want to avoid that....

Comment: @CosminAbabei Each day have from 0 to N ServiceController instances. The reason I put all of that in here, is because being new to angular I not sure what the problem really is. Also, instead of using a watch what should I do to verify when the value of  scope variable changes?

Comment: @DennisBraga how does the scope variable change? by user input or by some random event?

Comment: @CosminAbabei User mainly. Sometimes, e. g., I have to instantiate another service due to an user activity. Every day has a list of services, ranging the 0 to N. One of this services may take more than one day to execute. On this case, I have to generate another day to acomodate the service's second day operation. TL;DR: An user input triggers all kinds of manipulations on the $scope, but mainly the user manipulation triggers it.

Comment: Then you could use [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) on the input which changes **service.service_id**.

Comment: @CosminAbabei Sadly, sometimes, I need to change the service_id without the user **DIRECTLY** manipulates it. For example, the user changes the final destination city, so I have to update the list of services based on *Origin* and *Destination*, and the service_id ngChange would have to be called manually (what I think would not be semantically right).

Comment: Performance ins't a big issue yet. It's taking a time to primary loading, but is doing OK after it's loaded, and I'm happy with it. The real problem is that when I put a listener to a variable in a inner scope, is being called twice.

Comment: As you can see on the console.log image above, when the service_id changes, the change are called through two different scope. On if them seems to be the $rootScope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104866/discussion-between-cosmin-ababei-and-dennis-braga).

Comment: If you got what you are looking for please accept the answer

Comment: @DennisBraga you need to make a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this question, I checked the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03fn35c9/) you posted in the chat, but there is only js code. I don't think it is possible to guess what is wrong with your setup. It requires some debugging to find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may solve you issue. Even i had faced exactly the same as you are mentioning.

1. The reason for me was that, the controller was getting initialized again and there was a separate api call written in that, which was intended to load the page initially.
2. There can also be a scenario where you have assigned controller twice in the mark up.

Comment: This was exactaly what happened to me! You didn't got the bounty for like 14 sec. =/ Had already assigned to Robert. I was declarind an `ng-controller` for a div and calling a directive on that same controller, thus, instantiating it twice! That was the issue.

Comment: I exactly had the same scenario as described by @DennisBraga, removing declaration of ng-controller from view helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="day in package.days_info" class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
        <package-days-block day="day"></package-days-block>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='container-fluid' ng-repeat='service in day.services'>
    <service-block service="service"></service-block>
</div>
```

Pass `day` and `service` down into directives. Use two way binding to pass your `day` and `service` changes back up to package.days_info.

Remove your `ServiceController` It does not make much sense to ng-repeat a controller. `<service-block>` and `<package-days-block>` are E directive that handle logic.

Write only one watcher in your **PackageController** that watch `package.days_info` When your `day` or `service` change, it can simply find out and do something about it.

Just Chill and fix it.

Comment: The problem wasn't exactly that. But, the tip was nice! Very nice. Since I'll probably gonna use it from now on, I'll give you the bounty (and cause it expires in 22 min too). Thanks a lot.