# The changes on $scope created by ng-repeat + ng-controller do affect the parent's $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<div ng-controller='Controller1'>
    <div ng-repeat='item in things.list_itens' ng-controller='Controller2'>
    </div>
</div>
```

If on Controller2's $scope, I change something that comes from Controller1 by the **item** on the ng-repeat, it will affect the parent scope value?

```
// Controller2
$scope.item = "other thing";
```

It will take effect on the `$scope.things.list_itens[x]` on Controller1?

Comment: i think yes, it will change the value of controller1, becose javascript variables works with reference.

Comment: This is a simplified way for another problem that I get. Where I do exectly what is on the above (only in another scale) and I ended up with what appears to be two differents scopes.

Comment: Just wanted to be sure that I'm not going nuts!

Comment: Yes obviously it will change the value of controller1, because that controller2 come's after controller1. so it override the value of scope so I think you should use it in different way

Comment: @ojuskulkarni I thought so too, but as you can see in my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640381), this doesn't seem to be happening! If you could take a look, I'd grateful!