# Unit testing promises triggered by $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine to try and test code which has the following pattern:

(this is essentially a paginated database table load)

```
1. controller calls api on load
2. api.then updates $scope variable
3. controller $watch-es that $scope variable
  a. If new value meets criteria, call api again
  b. api.then updates $scope variable
  c. controller $watch-es the change
    i. eventually new value does not meet criteria and call chain is stopped
```

Right now my unit tests have 2 deferred promises. One to return a value that passes the $watch check, one to do the opposite. But, the 2nd promise's `then()` isn't invoked. Struggling to understand where I need to resolve promises and `$digest`

Check out a simplified plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/543Q5vGJqTYzkSvh

I'm expecting the `$scope.$watch` method to log something after the 2nd api call.

What's missing in my unit tests

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue after searching more about $watch getting triggered twice. It was due to me creating the mock controller in the first `beforeEach`, then recreating the controller in my `it` test. But i didn't create a fresh `$scope` for the new controller. So after the first api call that happens on load, when I did `$scope.$apply()`, both controller instances triggered the `$scope.$watch` change.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35842248/5362166

I went ahead and followed the controller creation pattern [here](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/)

my working code is in the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/543Q5vGJqTYzkSvh

I use jasmine's `done()` function.

Within my test, i get the most recent call of my mocked factory which returns a promise, invoke `then()`, and within the `then()` I digest the scope which triggers my watch function, which triggers the second api call. I repeat this process and get the most recent mocked call, invoke `then()`, digest scope again there and call `done()` finally; I see the output i'm expecting.